# how to add a custom view to system monitor on ubuntu

Tags: c++, performance

Is it possible to add a custom view to the system monitor ?
in windows it is possible to create performance monitors which you can then see visualized in the system monitor view - I was hoping for a similar possibility in Ubuntu

If this is not possible then an alternative way of viewing time related events from running apps would be a solution

[image]

Comment: why your tag is **C++**?

Comment: I was hoping for a simple C++ api for adding new performance monitors - currently I am writting events to different log files in .csv format, then importing to libraoffice calc and then visualizing it in a line plot graph - I would like to have it more dynamic and having a runtime performance monitor would do the trick